# The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am just starting cloud functions with firebase. Here is my first function.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import express from 'express';
import admin from "firebase-admin"
admin.initializeApp(functions.config())
console.log('Firebase Environment setup success')
const app1 = express()
app1.get("*", (request, response) => {
    response.send("bar")
})
const foo = functions.https.onRequest(app1)
module.exports = {
    foo
}
```

Everytime I run this code with the emulator suite with

```
firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

And I visit the url output on the console, I get the error:

> !  Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you
>   called initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as
>   the second argument. In most cases you only need to call
>   initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps,
>   pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique
>   name.
>       at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\Business\PhpstormProjects\gantt-flexx\node-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:42:28)
>       at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\Business\PhpstormProjects\gantt-flexx\node-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:88:28)
>       at new FirebaseAppError (C:\Users\Business\PhpstormProjects\gantt-flexx\node-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:122:28)
>       at FirebaseNamespaceInternals.initializeApp (C:\Users\Business\PhpstormProjects\gantt-flexx\node-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js:68:23)
>       at FirebaseNamespace.initializeApp (C:\Users\Business\PhpstormProjects\gantt-flexx\node-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js:392:30)
>       at Proxy. (C:\Users\Business\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:338:51)
>       at C:\Users\Business\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:641:30
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at fulfilled (C:\Users\Business\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:4:58)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) !  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.

Comment: You typically to call `initializeApp()` with no parameters when running in Cloud Functions, unless you have some special configuration to pass.

Comment: I already tried both. Same error/ You can try to reproduce this by yourself. I used the latest firebase admin and firebase functions  "firebase-admin": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0",

Comment: If you are certain this is a bug, please file your reproduction steps on GitHub.  Make sure you're using the latest version of firebase-tools. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools